# Adding property to nested object in union type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a set of objects that each have different types for an attribute object field depending on their value in a name field. I would like to create a function that can take any of these objects and add an id property to its attributes.

Here is a minimal example of what I have tried:

```
type Test1<T extends boolean> = {
  name: "test1";
  attrs: { t1: boolean; id: T extends true ? string : never };
};

type Test2<T extends boolean> = {
  name: "test2";
  attrs: { t2: string; id: T extends true ? string : never };
};

type Test<T extends boolean> = Test1<T> | Test2<T>;

const addId = (node: Test<false>, id: string): Test<true> => {
  return { name: node.name, attrs: { ...node.attrs, id } };
};
```

While this should produce the correct result, typescript raises an error:

```
Type '{ name: "test1" | "test2"; attrs: { id: string; t1: boolean; } | { id: string; t2: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Test<true>'.
  Type '{ name: "test1" | "test2"; attrs: { id: string; t1: boolean; } | { id: string; t2: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Test2<true>'.
    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type '"test1" | "test2"' is not assignable to type '"test2"'.
        Type '"test1"' is not assignable to type '"test2"'
```

I can resolve the error by discriminating the type before creating the new object as so:

```
const addId1 = (node: Test<false>, id: string): Test<true> => {
  if (node.name === "test1") {
    return { name: node.name, attrs: { ...node.attrs, id } };
  } else {
    return { name: node.name, attrs: { ...node.attrs, id } };
  }
};
```

but this becomes tedious when we have more than two types of nodes.

Is there any way to resolve this issue easily and in a way that generalizes to larger unions without relying on `any` or the like?

Comment: This is an issue with TS's support for "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended refactoring is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109); for this example it's as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpA8XW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, this should do the trick. I figured this was a common issue but wasn't sure where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript can't really handle "correlated [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). Your `Test<true>` and `Test<false>` types are [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) types, but TypeScript doesn't allow you to write a single block of code that operates on union types as if each union member were considered separately.  So even though `{ name: node.name, attrs: { ...node.attrs, id } }` is seen as working for both `Test1<T>` and `Test2<T>`, the compiler loses the thread for `Test<T>`.  You can write different code blocks for different cases, as you've shown with `if (node.name === "test1")`, but, as you've said, that's redundant.

The recommend workaround for cases like this is described in [microsoft/Typescript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Discriminated unions should be refactored to [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a basic key-value type or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over such a basic key-value type.  Read the GitHub issue for more detailed information.

In your case, the refactoring looks like this:

```
interface TestMap {
    test1: { t1: boolean }
    test2: { t2: string }
}

type Test<
    T extends boolean,
    K extends keyof TestMap = keyof TestMap
> = { [P in K]: {
    name: P,
    attrs: TestMap[P] & { id: T extends true ? string : never }
} }[K]
```

The basic `TestMap` key-value interface represents the relationship between the `name` property and the non-`id` `attrs`.  And `Test<T, K>` takes the place of your `Test<T>`.  It's a *distributive object type*, so `Test<T, keyof TestMap>` turns out to be equivalent to your `Test<T>`, and `Test<T, "test1">` is equivalent to your `Test1`, and `Test<T, "test2"> to` Test2`.  (So if you need them, you can still define them

```
type Test1<T extends boolean> = Test<T, "test1">
type Test2<T extends boolean> = Test<T, "test2">
```

.)  Anyway now your `addId()` function can be generic in `K extends keyof TestMap`, and it will just work:

```
const addId = <K extends keyof TestMap>(
    node: Test<false, K>, id: string): Test<true, K> => {
    return { name: node.name, attrs: { ...node.attrs, id } };
};
```

And when you call it, the compiler will distinguish between `"test1"` and `"test2"` cases properly, if you want:

```
declare const t1: Test1<false>;
const r1: Test1<true> = addId(t1, "x")

declare const t2: Test2<false>;
const r2: Test2<true> = addId(t2, "x")
```

But it can also accept the full union:

```
declare const t: Test<false>;
const r: Test<true> = addId(t, "z");
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUoGcIFkEAOqA3sKuatDgIwBcJldqARgPasA2UCYqAvmQpUIAJnrFKY1DhjgA5v2ADgEAJ4E0mHAB5B5dKigAPaGAAmWFuy48ANHtQBpQyajnLAayirWcDNjxCVABeVC8fPy1AgmAAPhCGAG0ABVRwJwBdcQcwBABbKHpk+wpUBAgIGCx6KPwCFIzUADIGEDMal1MLShgAVzQAfmlK+VR6MCgAN1hFPn5ExwzgYAB6FbS-H17hkA4OVAmoM0oAC2woFXVNAOptA2MuyzZObjB40Ki721QAImFqH6xS4afw4ER3TpubrPGxvBKfdDfP4BESA5ZIVhgHBlMxmACSx1C2mcDyhnm8vlB0ViAAocqwzIUqdpEBwsFBvo5Yt82vQZPIAJQ1ALaSr9TnveKkUowKAQXowXgSXIFcYMqAAOhVHLKFSq4lQGqNYHVGvKlSwPOOcz4AG4lPbloykBwELLUBisRBGMKaCyEGyoLF7Z7sTAmFFbmKgwkELiCTSINQkUYfgKnVAXW60KHvaJfaJ-YHg8Bc6gYFIouDo+8cfizImRCm0xms+6yxAC0X2SWyzAuzXY-GGxAkQAvNO21BrVCsDwIVTLFYAKjUIMjENJ7isLx4telFG19GRNB+9tK5v1DCT9BhrynvIwkO30dQQ35YAU4ymMztDuWa7XGCm6uNud57gkB7kEevzCKi54UJe1TXlIH5yA+7RPlu3Svu+IyfmMBw-jA-D2n+wJARAIGPDusK1hu6DxAAPlS4KMfay4rMAQA)